# Activation of network connection failed Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, network-manager, internet

EDIT:  The output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` as requested:

```
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/rt2800pci.conf line 1: ignoring bad line starting with 'sudo'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/rt2800pci.conf line 2: ignoring bad line starting with 'sudo'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/rt2800pci.conf line 3: ignoring bad line starting with 'sudo'
09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak] [8086:008a] (rev 34)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 BGN [8086:5325]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed on my Dell Inspiron N1150 laptop.  It is the only OS installed on it.  Even during installation I was unable to connect to the Internet, but thought nothing of it since the range on the wifi card when running Windows wasn't very good.  Once installation was finished and I was dropped onto the desktop, I encountered the error message "Activation of network connection failed" - this happened when connecting to my home WiFi network and the hotspot on my phone.

I've tried the following from this [page](https://appuals.com/activation-of-network-connection-failed-in-linux/):

Solution 1: Disable/Enable the Network Connection
Solution 5: Correct Date/Time Settings of Your System
Solution 8: Remove the Network Drivers from the Blacklist
Solution 9: Reinstall the Network Manager
Solution 11: Disable the Hardware Encryption by the Network Device

None of the above helped.  The rest either didn't apply (I am not dual-booting with Windows) or required an Internet connection (the last few).

A search on both Google and DuckDuckGo yielded nothing else useful, so I'm at my wits end right now.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: I've edited the post with the requested output.

Comment: You have some crap in `/etc/modprobe.d` after your attempts. Run `sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/rt2800pci.conf`.

Comment: Then please post output of `dmesg | grep iwl`